# Are there alternative to REST to access hosted data for an iOS App?

Tags: rest, node.js, amazon-simpledb

I am planning a REST interface for an iOS app with Restify + Nodejs storing data on Amazon SimpleDB.

Basic operations are create an account, store prefernces, store user generated content (data + media),  access data + computed result (computation happens on the server).

Are there any simpler alternative to using REST (Restify + Nodejs) for auth and access?

Comment: "Simple"... such a simple word.. means so many things.. What do yo mean by "simple". Simple could be easy but could also be not complex (for example some might say assembly is simple but it is generally not easy). Also are you asking for alternatives to REST (architecture) or NodeJS (implementation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as an API goes, I don't think it gets much simpler than a clean RESTful interface.

For Auth, you could always avoid doing it yourself and lean on an existing service people may already have like Facebook or Open ID.

In then end, the code you'll write to handle those is probably pretty close to what you'd write if you did your own authorization.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I am using NodeJs + Restify for the backend on AWS using their SimpleDB.